# Is match a language feature?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm teaching myself Scala and I have sort of a philosophical question.  Is pattern matching a *language* feature of Scala, or just a library feature?  To put it another way, could I, were I sufficiently skilled, write `xmatch`, a function that was identical to `match` in every way except the name?  Actually, I think those are two slightly different questions: is matching a library feature, and *could* it be a library feature?

I was thinking of trying to re-write match, purely as an exercise, but I wanted some assurance it was possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pattern matching is a language feature, of which the `match` statement is only the most notable example.  Here are two other commonly-used examples:

```
val List(x,y,(z: Int,w: Int)) = List("one","two",(3,4))
for ((text,i) <- List(("one",1),("two",2))) println(text + " = " + i)
```

So, no, you can't do that on your own.  The language does not allow you to define new ways to create variables, so these things can only happen with language support.

The `match` statement itself uses the pattern-matching variable-creation support inside the language, but otherwise could in principle be implemented as a library feature.  However, it would be inefficient in several cases:

```
// This is implemented with fast jumps, not slow if-then-else!
n match {
  case 0 => // Do action 0
  case 1 => // Do action 1
  case 2 => // Do action 2
  case _ => // Do default action
}

// This is tail recursive, so you won't overflow the stack!
def recursiveMatch(xs: List[Any]): List[Any] = xs match {
  case (x @ Int) :: rest => recursiveMatch(rest)
  case _ => xs
}
```

So, all in all, no, you can't write pattern matching yourself, and while you could write the match statement, there are advantages in using the existing one.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `match` used to be implemented in the library, I've heard. The Change Log in the Scala Reference indicates `match` became a reserved keyword on version 2.0, at which point `object.match { ... }` ceased to be a valid syntax as well.

It is rather easy to implement it in principle:

```
implicit def toMyMatch[T](obj: T) = new {
    def myMatch[R](f: T => R) = f(obj)
}
```

I don't know the exact reasons why it ceased to be implemented this way.

Comment: Exact reasons? Probably because having `match` as a method prevents tail call optimization on tail calls made inside the partial function.

Comment: how does this allow case analysis?

Comment: @pelotom `f` must be a partial function for that. I would change the snippet above to something like `def myMatch[R](f: PartialFunction[T, R]) = f(obj)`

Comment: ok, so you can implement `match` as a library, but not `case`, which is where the real magic happens

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is definitely a language feature. That said, because writing control flow structures in Scala is so easy (and pattern matching is robust), you could easily write your own `match` (compared to other languages).

`match`, on the other hand, is still a part of the language core (I think), but it behaves much more like something in the library. It feels so organic because of how powerful pattern matching is.

That said, yeah, you could definitely rewrite `match`.

Comment: There seems to be no real answer in this answer. It's all fluffy words and praise...